Is there any way to add the border or customise the border in quill_html_editor?
I am not able to create the border or customise the border. Is there any way to customise or add the border and border radius using quill_html_editor.
I trying to do below design, but i am not able to achieve the border, is there any way to do in flutter.
https://marketplace.canva.com/EAFiSdV35zk/3/0/1600w/canva-gold-and-beige-stars-student-of-the-month-school-award-3dYFf6T4e8w.jpg

simply wrap it in a Container and give it a decoration, using border and borderRadius.

can you share the code.

You will find your answer here
Example-
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.pink[800], // Set border color
            width: 3.0),   // Set border width
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0)), // Set rounded corner radius
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 10,color: Colors.black,offset: Offset(1,3))] // Make rounded corner of border
      ),
      child: Text("My demo styling"),
    )


Inside quill_html_editor package we have table option, for that how to change the border radius and colour.

Oh did you tried different package for custom modification ? like 'html_editor_enhanced'

I am using this package (quill_html_editor 2.2.8)
https://pub.dev/packages/quill_html_editor
